# Remove an argument from %*

Tags: windows, batch-file

In windows batch, I would like to remove one or more specific arguments from %*

For example, I want to remove **--dev** from a command like this:

```
python --dev -c "print 'hello world'"
```

How would I do that?

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set i=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
  IF NOT %%x == --dev (
     set /A i+=1
     set "args[!i!]=%%~x"
     )
)
:: expecting args to be -c "print 'hellow world'"
echo running: python %args%
python %args%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to emulate array notation in your batch, which doesn't really work. What you're essentially doing is creating new variables like:

```dos
args[0]=--dev
```

which you would then need to call with `%args[0]%`.

## Variable content replacement

Instead, you can use variable replacement like this:

```dos
@ECHO OFF

set args=%*
set args=%args:--dev =%

:: expecting args to be -c "print 'hello world'"
echo running: python %args%
python %args%
```

This way you don't need delayed expansion or `for` loops.

## `for` loop

If you would rather keep your `for` loop, then you could use something like this:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set args=
for %%x in (%*) do (
  IF NOT [%%x] == [--dev] (
     set "args=!args! %%x"
     )
)
:: expecting args to be -c "print 'hello world'"
echo running: python %args%
python %args%
```

**Further reading:**

- [Replace syntax - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: A good answer, but I don't see the point in using the `args[]` variables. Why not start with `set "args= "`, then in the first loop simply `set "args=!args! %%~x`, without the need for a second loop? The argument string will have two leading blanks, which will be ignored in the program schedule line.

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure why I got that original `for` loop stuck in my head. I've updated the answer with your suggestions. I didn't use `%%~x` because that removes necessary quotes form the arguments.

Comment: Yes, I was unsure whether quotes should be included: it was only because the questioner excluded them that I did the same, although my instinct was to include them.